# My first option value does not display my hidden div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have onchange select event, my problem is the first value of select option value was not load the javascript until I select it into other value and back to first value. How I can trigger to load my script when I load it.

```
function test(){
        showOther = function(val){
            if(val && val !='SHOPPING' && val !='NEGOTIATED'){
                document.getElementById('OtherDiv').style.display = '';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('OtherDiv').style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            }
            window.onload = test;

<select id="txt10" onchange="showOther(this.value);" class="textbox1" tabindex="6" style="width:150px;height:23px;">
        <option value="<?php echo $mod; ?>" style="text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo "<div style='text-transform:uppercase;color:blue;'>".$row['mode_of_procurement']."</div>"; ?></option>
        <option value="BIDDING" style="text-transform:uppercase;">BIDDING</option>
        <option value="RFQ" style="text-transform:uppercase">RFQ</option>
        <option value="NEGOTIATED" style="text-transform:uppercase">NEGOTIATED</option>
        <option value="SHOPPING" style="text-transform:uppercase">SHOPPING</option>
```

Comment: Try setting style.display to block instead of an empty string

Comment: I already try it,nothing happens, my hidden div didn't display when $mod is =BIDDING or RFQ, but when I click to the other values and back to first value which is $mod, the hidden div display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var value = this.value; if (value != "SHOPPING" && value !='NEGOTIATED'){ 
    $("#OtherDiv").css("display","block"); 
      }else{           
    $("#OtherDiv").css("display","none"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(val && val !='SHOPPING' && val !='NEGOTIATED'){
            document.getElementById('OtherDiv').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('OtherDiv').style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: it has the same results :( help me please, I'm new in javascript.

Comment: Hi if ur task is just wanna show or hide div based on condition Jquery   toggle/toggleclass might do it..below is a link of toggle jquery             http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: My task is show the hidden div if the value from the database is = BIDDING and RFQ, the codes works properly except the hidden div doesn't show if the first value select, but when i select the other values, and back to the first value, it runs correctly.

Comment: Hey Papao check this fiddle ur task is done as expected....enjoy include jquery libs as i have used it.            http://jsbin.com/AquCUbe/2/edit

Comment: thanks for your help and time. But what I want to do is <option value $row['mode'];> if the value of row is ==bidding or ==rfq then is display automatically the hidden div, but when I get into the page, select = bidding but the hidden div doesn't show until I select into other option and click back select the $row.

Comment: Hi papao sry but the fiddle does exactly wat u have said in this comment.."if the value of row is ==bidding or ==rfq then is display automatically the hidden div,"..any way gud luck...

Comment: I missed to set the body to onload, but your answer was perfect. ty for your time :)